# how to change background of overflow menuitem

Tags: android, menu, background, overflow

I am trying to change the blue background of a focussed/pressed menuitem in the overflow menu.

I'm talking about this:

[image]

I think I've overwritten every possible attribute from the `Theme`and `Theme.Holo` in `Themes.xml` and went to each style in `Styles.xml` but couldn't change the blue background.

**EDIT**
i figured out that the style i should override is `android:dropDownListViewStyle`

but it didn't work at all.
but then i changed the theme from `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.Holo.Light` and guess what? it worked!!

so, can anyone shed some light on this?? how can i change the color on a theme with `DarkActionBar`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, i found a solution for my problem: [link to a post in the ActionBarSherlock google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/actionbarsherlock/AxB6shftiK0/HbvsrBgMpsoJ)

i've overseen this entry: `android:actionBarWidgetTheme` in the `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` theme.

now all i had to do is define a theme that overrides `Theme.Holo` with one style in it: `<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/myDropDownListView</item>` and point to this theme instead.

```
<!-- theme referenced by actionBarWidgetTehme style -->
<style name="Theme.DropDown.Dark" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/myDropDownListView</item>
</style>

<!-- my main theme -->
<style name="DarkActionBarRedActionMode" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.DropDown.Dark</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

declare a selector drawable, and put it as background of listview item.

refer to [drawable resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Comment: i know what you intending, but that doesn't work - at least for this.  
i have already changed a `listSelector` to a resource. and honestly, i wasn't thinking i have troubles changing this one as well. but first, i need to know witch element it is.

Comment: do you use layoutinflater to inflate a layout or simple_list_item_1? if using simple_list_item_1, maybe can try using custom adapter

Comment: what i mean is: to change the background of the overflow button i needed to change the `android:actionOverflowButtonStyle` style and override `<item name="android:background">...</item>`. i assume this background thing will be as well a `listSelector`...

Comment: well, this i a native actionbar. so i don't do anything particularly

Comment: do you declare style in 2 attributes? one with android prefix and one without prefix?

Comment: it's a native actionbar. no sherlock. so i only use the android: prefix