# Change default blue color in android holo theme to orange (or anything else)

Tags: android, styles, themes

I am using holo theme in my app:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

I want to change the default blue color to orange. I thought it would be simple. However, after Googling all day, I still don't have a solution that works for me.

(Note: This should also be applicable to dialogs. By default dialog titles and lines are blue.)

Say if default is like this:

[image: From Blue]

I want to be like this:

[image: To Orange]

Please help. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I know about the style generator at http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ 
That's where from I got these images. But I don't want all of this, it has a lot of images and other stuff which makes app larger in size. Let me know if there's a way to tweak the default themes.

Comment: Not sure but it seems you are looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324795/how-to-change-background-of-overflow-menuitem)

Comment: The style generator generates 64 files, which seems like a lot - but they only take up 32.2kb of space, which is tiny. It seems to only override styling on activities (not dialogs) though. It would be nice if there was a simple CSS like "highlight-color: orange", but I think the styles as generated by the style generator are the only way to do it.

Comment: @George Really wish if there was something like a property where we could've specified the color. Hope Google provides this in some future API version. By then we'll have to manage with something else. :(

Answer (score 1):

This is not applicable by changing a Property because it is related to some drawable (some 9patch png). There is a really good website to build the drawable of widgets by your **desired color**.

Working with, is simple and straight forward and it generate PNGs for the widgets you select not all, to keep the size of your project small.

Here it is:
http://android-holo-colors.com/

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement use following library i think it is useful for you

[PagerSlidingTabStrip](http://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)